# CURL/PHP/Apache - Why won't this CURL/Simplexml request to Vimeo work?

Tags: curl, simplexml, vimeo

The below function should be outputting a Vimeo thumbnail.  Its not returning anything.  I have tested for `$id` and it is passing into the function, and it is a valid vimeo ID for a video.  When I replace the `$out = xxx` with
`$out = 'hello';`, nothing comes out.  This leads me to believe no records are being returned in the xml call.  Curl 7.12.1 is installed.  What else could be a problem here?

```
function vimeo_thumbnail()
{
    global $TMPL, $DB, $SESS;

    $video_id       = $TMPL->fetch_param('id');

    if(!$video_id) {
        return;
    }

    // API endpoint
    $api_endpoint = 'http://www.vimeo.com/api/v2/video/'.$video_id.'.xml';

    // Curl helper function
    function curl_get($url) {
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        $return = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $return;
    }

    // Load the user info and clips
    $video_info = simplexml_load_string(curl_get($api_endpoint));

    foreach ($video_info->video as $video) {
        $out = '<img src="'.$video->thumbnail_medium.'" />';
    }

    $this->return_data .= $out;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the status of ur curl request use something like this in ur function

```
$return = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
print_r($info);
```

this will tell u alot about the request and u will know what exactly is happening to ur request.. and u can continue to debug from there.

Comment: Thanks Sab.  Turns out I'm on a PHP4 server so simplexml_load_string wont' work.

Can you possibly give me a replacement for this?

Comment: maybe this will help?
http://www.webmaster-talk.com/php-forum/170192-problem-with-simplexml_load_string-and-php4.html